# Смешанная арифметика и friend вне шаблона класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Здравствуйте!

Хочу вынести friend-функцию оператора за определение класса:

```
template<typename T>
class A;

template <typename T>
const A<T> operator + (A<T> a, const A<T>& b);

template <typename T>
class A {
...
public:
    A(){...}
    A(T t){...}
    const A& operator += (const A& r);
    friend const A operator + <T> (A a, const A& b);
};

template <typename T>
const A<T>& A<T>::operator += (const A<T>& r) {...}

template <typename T>
const A<T> operator + (A<T> a, const A<T>& b) {
    return a += b;
}
```

Однако с этим кодом проблема: `A<int> += 1` работает, а вот `A<int> + 1` — нет:

```
int main() {
    A<int> (1) += 2;  // Ok
    A<int> (1) + A<int> (2);  // Ok
    A<int> (1) + 2;  // Error!
    return 0
}
```

Т. е. смешанная арифметика не работает. Вопрос — почему, и как правильно ее сделать?

Comment: `+=` не может принимать `const`, т. к. он обязан модифицировать левый операнд.

Comment: @VladD, почему? Он же не изменяет правый операнд.

Comment: @Zelta: А, и правда, вы же задаёте покамест оператор как функцию-член. Может быть, в этом случае не обязательно _возвращать_ `const`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется, я нашел причину.

При вызове шаблонной функции не происходит приведения типов:

Если вызвать обычную функции с сигнатурой, к примеру, `int a(int, int)`, то компилятор попытается привести все операнды к инту.

Если же вызвать шаблон с сигнатурой `<T> b(<T>, <T>)` от разных типов (`b(int_val, double_val)`, к примеру), то возникает проблема: каким типом считать `<T>`? Приводить ли `int_val` к типу `double_val`, или наоборот.

Если же внести friend функцию внутрь класса, такой проблемы не происходит:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
...
public:
    A(){...}
    A(T t){...}
    const A& operator += (const A& r);
    friend const A operator + <T> (A a, const A& b) {
        return a += b;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, у вас класс недописанный, а во-вторых, своему типу при объявлении нужно дать имя (нельзя тип складывать с другим типом, складывают объекты). См.:

```
int main(){
    A<int> theA(1);  // здесь есть имя а ниже нет!
    //A<int> (1) + A<int> (2);  // Ok
    //A<int> (1) + 2;  // Error!

    return 0;
}
```

См. ещё:

```
int main(){
        A<int> theA(1), theB(5);  // здесь есть имя!
        A<int> theC = theA + theB;  // вот так выполняют сложение

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: > нельзя тип складывать с другим типом

Ну это и называется смешанной арифметикой.

Вызов `A<int> (1) + 2` должен развернуться в `operator + (A<int> (1), 2)`. Проблема в том, что неявное преобразование типов не работает в случае с шаблонами.

P.S.  Я не собираюсь выкладывать сюда все 300 строк моего класса. Так что, конечно, он недописанный. Я ему еще и название сменил на `A`.

P.P.S.

> своему типу при объявлении нужно дать имя

А можно подробнее? Почему? Если он мне нужен только в одном месте, почему бы не объявить его безымянным?

Comment: @Zelta операции сложение производятца только с объектами, но не с классами (класс - это просто описание будующего объекта), у вас синтаксис нарушен. А безымянный объект создает компилятор на границе блоков (например, вывод из функции).

Comment: экземпляр это и есть объект. а у вас его нет, указан только тип (смотри ответ обновил)

Comment: @perfect, `A<int> (1) + A<int> (2);`. В этой строке происходит следующее (по крайней мере должно):

1. Вызывается конструктор A(1) для A типа int. Получаем безымянный экземпляр класса.

2. Вызывается конструктор A(2) для A типа int. Получаем еще один безымянный экземпляр класса.

3. Складываетм два получившихся экземпляра класса и возвращаем результат сложения — тоже безымянный экземпляр класса.

Comment: @Zelta у вас не будет не вызвано ни одного конструктора, пока вы сами не создадите экземпляр класса.

Comment: @perfect, так я его создаю, вон в скобочках инициализирующее значение указано!

Comment: @Zelta а где имя экземпляра класса, которому вы это значение передаете?

Comment: @perfect, ну нету имени, безымянный он.